# master and slave configuration in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for master-slave node configuration (distributed builds) in Azure DevOps, i.e. many slaves work for a master. It also allows you to run jobs on different environments like Linux, Windows, MacOS, etc. The job of a Slave is to do as they are told to, which involves executing build jobs dispatched by the Master. I have searched for all possible options, but couldn't find the reference/guidelines to configure it in Azure Devops.

Answer (score 0):

that is the default behaviour for Azure Devops. It acts like a master and all the agents are slaves just running their jobs. You can use hosted or self-hosted agents - doesn't matter. they all act the same way.